# Jekyll including source code via file

Tags: web, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to include source code of a c program in my jekyll pages with download link.

I have searched jekyll documentation and also stackoverflow but nothing is working.
Can anyone point out the right way to do this.

```
---
source: ["inf.c","find.c","error.c","stu.c","info.c"]
---
{% for c in page.source %}

<tr>
<th>
   <a href="{{c}}">
   {{c}}
    </a>
   </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>
    {% highlight ruby %}
    {% include {{page.permalink}}{{c}} %}
    {% endhighlight %}
    </th>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your code snippets a re stored in `/code` folder as `a.c`, `b.c` and so on.

Your page `code.html` can be like this one :

```
{% for c in page.source %}

  {% capture filePath %}/code/{{c}}{% endcapture %}

  <a href="{{filePath}}">{{c}}</a>

  {% highlight c %}
  {% include_relative {{ filePath }} %}
  {% endhighlight %}
{% endfor %}
```